# Can GPS data be sent from the iPhone while App is running in memory/background

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4

I'm looking to put together an app that will figure out other iPhone users in the same area.

I'm curious as to know if it is possible that an app can run in the iPhone memory or in the background and send push notifications to the owner of the phone when someone with the same app is in the area.

I gather I can do this if the App is actively turned on, but am wondering if this is possible say if the users phone is in his pocket for example.

Comment: Hello curious in seattle. I'm looking for an app- a barcodescanner-  running in the background. Have you found out whether it is possible to run a small app in background?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160431/is-background-gps-location-logging-possible-on-iphone-4-or-3gs-running-on-ios4