# Iphone, how save coordinate gps in background?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios4, core-location

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is background GPS\location logging possible on iPhone 4 or 3GS running on iOS4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160431/is-background-gps-location-logging-possible-on-iphone-4-or-3gs-running-on-ios4)

**I want to save the GPS coordinates when the application goes into background mode, how can i do? thanks!!**

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in getting Core Location updates while in the background, you might wanna check the significant location changes service and the region monitoring service in Core Location (only available in iPhone 4, and probably iPad 2 with 3G). You can also opt to receive regular GPS location updates in the background by including `location` in the `UIBackgroundModes` array of your `Info.plist`.

If you're just interested in saving the last location before your app was sent to the background, just save the latitude and longitude in `NSUserDefaults`.

Comment: I want to thank the former, I want to save the GPS coordinates
(latitude and longitude) every second, even when the application goes in background, I have configured the application:
Add the key named UIBackgroundModes
  with key: item 0 value: location
is that correct?
how can I make these coordinates to use them once restored
application?
I hope I was clear, and I thank you very much for your
availability.

Comment: Just handle the location updates the same way as if you're in the foreground. Just make sure you don't do any UI updates while in the background. So, you can save the `CLLocation` objects into an `NSArray` that you can work with later.