# how take information of location when the application go in background?

Tags: ios4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is background GPS\location logging possible on iPhone 4 or 3GS running on iOS4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160431/is-background-gps-location-logging-possible-on-iphone-4-or-3gs-running-on-ios4)

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Suspend the application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5317231/suspend-the-application)

I want take information of location (GPS) when the app go in background, for example the app X go in background and i want save the coordinate gps at the time 
(Lat:12,889 Long:9,231 time: 4:56) 
(Lat:12,889 Long:9,231 time: 4:57)
(Lat:12,889 Long:9,231 time: 4:58)
i want take this information every 1 min,
and when resume the app, i want use this vector of information.
Thanks!
I don't know if this is possible with iphone ios 4, but with 3 is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Please see this
[Is background GPS\location logging possible on iPhone 4 or 3GS running on iOS4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160431/is-background-gps-location-logging-possible-on-iphone-4-or-3gs-running-on-ios4)

and note that this will drain the battery faster if your app has to be in the background for a long time.